# When can I become a vampire lord?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I know you get the chance to become a vampire lord in either branch of the story (after brining Serana to the castle if you betray Dawnguard or before entering Soul Cairn if you don't), will I be able to become a vampire lord later if I refuse/cure my vampirism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serana can turn you at any time after completing the Dawnguard questline, unless you send her off to get her vampirism cured.

Comment: You sure like to answer your own post huh? Also, sorry for the wrong answer.

Comment: @Hugabooga no probs. It's not like I'm going to stop playing the game just because one of my questions on it is unanswered, so sometimes I learn the answer on my own, might as well share it.